# Post WooCommerce order to remote database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 servers, on 1st server I have WooCommerce store and on 2nd server I have a backup MySQL database. I want to save every new WooCommerce order to 2nd database as well as on 1st database (which get stored by default on 1st server database).

For this, I tried using `woocommerce_new_order` hook and configured 2nd server database connection inside the function. But, I don't know how to programmatically create a WooCommerce Order on 2nd server database.

The code I have so far is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'my_order_details',  1, 1  );
        function my_order_details($order_id){
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $db = 'database';
        $new_wpdb = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        if (!$new_wpdb) {
            echo mysqli_error($new_wpdb);
        }
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $order_num = $order_id;
        $order_amount = get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_total', true);
        }
```

Please tell me how can I programmatically store a copy of order on 2nd database.

Comment: This isn't the right approach. You should set up replication at the database level if you're looking for a backup

Comment: can't I create a duplicate order on another database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocommerce api to create an order on the remote server:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-an-order

Or you can create the same records in the remote database in sql. You should take care of the identity fields manually.

In general quite difficult to make the two databases in sync.

prefered to replicate or simple backup-restore the database regularly (hourly).